# Cesium js, Draw line binding a label to a position

Tags: labeling, line, cesium, pixel

I would like to draw a line binding a entity to its label with an offset.
CesiumJS allows to offset the label, however its not possible to draw a line (or polyline) from a position to an offset like the red line in this image.

[image]

How can i do it? any sugestion?

i'm using pixel offset. but there is no problem to use eye offset

```
 labels.add({
        position: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-75.1641667, 29.9522222),
        text: 'Another label',
        pixelOffset: new Cesium.Cartesian2(100,-100)

    });
```

Comment: What kind of offset are you using?  PixelOffset?  Can you post code that creates the point and its label?

Comment: replied on edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is probably a billboard with an image of the line on it.  The length will never change if it's a pixelOffset.  You can put an image of a white line, and use the color property to set any other color.

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');
var scene = viewer.scene;

var labels = scene.primitives.add(new Cesium.LabelCollection());
labels.add({
    position: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-75.1641667, 29.9522222),
    text: 'Another label',
    pixelOffset: new Cesium.Cartesian2(100, -100)
});

var billboards = scene.primitives.add(new Cesium.BillboardCollection());
billboards.add({
    color : Cesium.Color.RED,
    image : 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQAAABkCAYAAABw4pVUAAAAyUlEQVR42u3RQRHAMBADsQRWwRRosBTMxSzqh3bGBKy19Hsz82QnG28UYQApw0ifV4owstczRRjZ9g4MGDBgCAYMwYAhGDAEA4ZgwIABAwYMGIIBQzBgCAYMwYAhGDBgwIABA4ZgwBAMGIIBQzBgCAYMGDBgwIAhGDAEA4ZgwBAMGIIBAwYMGDBgCAYMwYAhGDAEA4ZgwIABAwYMGIIBQzBgCAYMwYAhGDBgwIABA4ZgwBAMGIIBQzBgCAYMGDBgwKgDgVEGAqOoCyAqoIT32fmkAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC',
    pixelOffset: new Cesium.Cartesian2(50, -50),
    position : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-75.1641667, 29.9522222)
});
```